# Make one row bold Stata esttab regression to LaTeX

Tags: latex, stata

I am trying to export Stata regression results to a LaTeX table. The below minimal example accomplishes everything I need, except that I would love the entire row ("make") to be bold, i.e. all point estimates wrapped in "\textbf{}" or any other solution that makes it bold.

```
sysuse auto, clear
label var make "\textbf{Make}"
eststo clear
eststo: reghdfe price make mpg rep trunk, abs(foreign)
eststo: reghdfe price make mpg rep , abs(foreign)       
esttab using "test.tex", replace p ar2 star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses regular expressions to wrap any combination of (digits,dot,digits), not surrounded by parentheses and not preceded by < (for p values in footnote), with \textbf{}.

```
sysuse auto, clear
label var make "\textbf{Make}"
eststo clear
eststo: reghdfe price mpg rep trunk, abs(foreign)
eststo: reghdfe price mpg rep , abs(foreign)       
esttab using "test.tex", replace p ar2 star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01)

import delimited test.tex, delim("`=char(10)'") clear
replace v1 = ustrregexra(v1, "(?<!\(|<)(-?\d+\.\d+)(?!\))", "\\textbf{\$1}")
export delimited using test.tex, delim("`=char(10)'") novarnames replace
```

Comment: I only need one row bolded, but this  can easily be worked into your solution

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that, should be easy to solve with an `if` condition indeed