# Stata esttab output to Latex : changing font size

Tags: stata

Sometimes you must export using from Stata to Latex very long or very large regression tables such that it does not fit into a single page. This commonly happens in preliminary analysis is you keep a maximum of control variables and tests various models side by side. One solution is to modify fonts manually in the Latex output *ResultsTable.tex* file by adding *\footnotesize* or *\tiny* after \caption:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Main Results} \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
```

But this must be repeated each time a modification is made to the table.

What would be the approach to modify the Latex's font size directly into STATA using the esttab package?

```
esttab m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 using "ResultsTable.tex", replace booktabs compress
```

Thank you for any advice on this!

Comment: The options of `esttab` are documented in `help esttab`. If this doesn't allow enough flexibility you can read in the resulting tex file using `import delimited` and add your changes using `replace if`

Comment: For example, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336503/make-one-row-bold-stata-esttab-regression-to-latex

Comment: I think @Wouter's linked solution is a great solution for edits to the body of the table (i.e. the part not controlled by `prehead` and `postfoot`), but for edits to the "head" the answer below is also nice, and would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though `help esttab` is always useful, most solutions to tricky `esttab`-to-Latex problems rely on the fact that `esttab` is a wrapper for `estout`, and are easily solved with `estout`'s `prehead` option... which is not documented under `esttab`.

Here is a quick [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that approximates the information in your question:

```
sysuse auto

reg price mpg 
estimates store m1
reg price mpg rep78
estimates store m2 
reg price mpg rep78 headroom
estimates store m3

esttab m1 m2 m3 ///
    using "out1.tex", ///
    replace booktabs compress ///
    title("Main Results")
```

This produces a `.tex` file containing a table with the following header:

```latex
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Main Results}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\toprule
```

To add `\footnotesize` you'll need to pass the full header from `\begin{table}` to `\toprule` (since you're using `booktabs`) to the `prehead()` option as follows:

```
esttab m1 m2 m3 ///
    using "out2.tex", ///
    replace booktabs compress ///
    prehead(`"\begin{table}[htbp]\centering"' `"\footnotesize"' ///
            `"\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}"' ///
            `"\caption{Main Results}"' ///
            `"\begin{tabular}{l*{@M}{c}}"' ///
            `"\toprule"' ) //
```

Note that each line in the `.tex` output is wrapped with a back-tick and apostrophe, and that the `\begin{tabular}{l*{@M}{c}}` statement references `@M` rather than explicitly stating the number of columns.
This produces a `.tex` file containing a table with the following header:

```latex
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\footnotesize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Main Results}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\toprule
```